# WebPart that redirect if user is not in a specific SharePoint security group

Tags: security, redirect, sharepoint, web-parts

Does anybody know of a webpart, webpart code or client code that will do this?

I'd like to give a security group contribute to a sepecific list, but want to customize copies of the forms they can run and would like to make sure they can't run other speicfic forms for the list.

When the webpart sees they are not in a specific security group it will redirect them to an error page or some other page.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a webpart that runs this code:

```
if (!SPContext.Current.Web.SiteGroups["groupname"].ContainsCurrentUser)
{
  SPUtility.Redirect("url", SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
}
```